# Appending to SQLAlchemy mutable list (getting can't adapt type "Post" error)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, mutable

I'm using SQLAlchemy/Postgres/Flask for a web app. I am trying to append to the `posts` list in my user table. The code for using a mutable list is here which `MutableList` class I copied and pasted: http://www.kirang.in/2014/08/09/creating-a-mutable-array-data-type-in-sqlalchemy/

However, when I submit the form that calls the route below, I get an error "can't adapt type 'Post'." It does print out the "MADE IT" print statement though.

If I don't use db.session.commit(), the submit goes through but the posts list remains empty after `select * from users`. How do I append to this `posts` list in my db?

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    posts = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(db.String)), unique = False)

    def __init__(self,username,first_name,last_name):
        self.username = username
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.posts = []

    def add_post(self, post):
        self.posts.append(post)
```

in my routes:

```
@app.route('/add_user', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    .... # form code
    if not db.session.query(User).filter(User.email == email).count():
                    f = User(username, first_name, last_name, gender, email, photo, age)
                    db.session.add(f)
                    db.session.commit()

                    first_post = Post("abaric","Cars","5","Cars fan!")
                    f.add_post(first_post)
                    db.session.commit()

                    print("MADE IT")
                    return render_template('success.html')
```

Comment: Your list has type `ARRAY(db.String)`. Why do you expect it to accept objects of type `Post`?

Comment: This had the feel of an XY problem. Should you perhaps be using foreign keys and possibly association tables to link users and posts, and then a `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship()`?

Comment: Oops, you're totally right- it would only accept strings! Would it be possible to start a Mutable List of Post types? I'd rather keep it all in one table.